# Setup Java SE 6 as execution environment in OSX Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

My eclipse currently uses JavaSE-1.8 by default. But for a specific reason I want to use Java SE 6. 
I have done the following:

1. My Project -> configure build path -> Java compiler -> Compiler compliance level -> 1.6
2. Project -> properties -> Libraries -> remove 1.8 and Add Library -> Alternate JRE -> .. ?

Under the dropdown, only 1.8 is available. 
How do I setup Java SE 1.6 in my eclipse as default runtime environment ?
Also, under the archive section of oracle [link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase6-419409.html) I am unable to find a version for 1.6. Where do I download JRE 1.6 from ?
where do I download it from ?

Comment: Java 6 on mac was delivered by Apple itself, not Oracle. I would try to just get along with a Java 8 runtime and compliance set to Java 6 as you've done in step 1, that should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to use [Execution Environments](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Execution_Environments)<sup>1</sup>, not direct references to JREs installed on your system. Execution Environment is an abstraction of installed JREs that allow projects to be configured without knowing the details of what JREs are installed.

To set up a JRE in Eclipse, go to the Preferences > Java > Installed JREs and follow [the instructions](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fpreferences%2Fjava%2Fdebug%2Fref-execution_environments.htm) to set up the alternate (1.6 in your case) JRE/JDK. Once you have your 1.6 JRE set up, go to the Execution Environments sub-page in the preferences and mark it as the default for the **JavaSE-1.6** Execution Environment.

Now, back in your project's Build Path properties, under **Libraries**, select the **JRE System Library** and use the **Edit...** button; there you can choose the **Execution Environment** *JavaSE-1.6* that you just configured.

---

You can download "legacy" Java 1.6 JRE from Apple [here](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?locale=en_US). But beware that doing so might make it the default JRE for your entire OS, which isn't likely to be desirable for most people.

---

<sup>1</sup>Some content on that page is specific to plug-in development, but the concepts of Execution Environments apply to any Java project in Eclipse. Just ignore the parts about OSGi and Plug-in Development (PDE).